# aiogram media group message id

Tags: python, aiogram, media

Мне необходимо получить message id отправленного ботом сообщения, которое представляет из себя медиагруппу. Я пробовал использовать стандартный подход для обычных сообщений

```
mg = await message.answer_media_group(media_group)
print(mg['message_id'])
```

Но это не сработало, так как в отличие от обычного сообщения media_group представляет собой черт знает что:

```
[<Message {"message_id": 431, "from": {"id": *****, "is_bot": true, "first_name": "****", "username": "*****_bot"}, "chat": {"id": *****, "first_name": ***", "username": "****", "type": "private"}, "date": 1674336461, "media_group_id": "13394605295606250", "photo": [{"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkDAAIBr2PMLp2fVvJw7q2HH6V9mV3M1GHhAAKZwzEbZdpgSqBCllcAAQwKpwEAAwIAA3MAAy0E", "file_unique_id": "***", "file_size": 1327, "width": 90, "height": 51}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkDAAIBr2PMLp2fVvJw7q2HH6V9mV3M1GHhAAKZwzEbZdpgSqBCllcAAQwKpwEAAwIAA20AAy0E", "file_unique_id": "******", "file_size": 17052, "width": 320, "height": 180}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkDAAIBr2PMLp2fVvJw7q2HH6V9mV3M1GHhAAKZwzEbZdpgSqBCllcAAQwKpwEAAwIAA3gAAy0E", "file_unique_id": "*****", "file_size": 95884, "width": 800, "height": 450}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkDAAIBr2PMLp2fVvJw7q2HH6V9mV3M1GHhAAKZwzEbZdpgSqBCllcAAQwKpwEAAwIAA3kAAy0E", "file_unique_id": "AQADmcMxG2XaYEp-", "file_size": 151789, "width": 1280, "height": 720}], "caption": "********"}>, <Message {"message_id": 432, "from": {"id": *****, "is_bot": true, "first_name": "*****", "username": "****"}, "chat": {"id": *****, "first_name": "***", "username": "*****", "type": "private"}, "date": 1674336461, "media_group_id": "13394605295606250", "photo": [{"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkDAAIBsGPMLp2JSUJTTnhbrEhMsgyqbdvoAAKYwzEbZdpgSqdSvY8KTXrjAQADAgADcwADLQQ", "file_unique_id": "*****", "file_size": 996, "width": 90, "height": 51}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkDAAIBsGPMLp2JSUJTTnhbrEhMsgyqbdvoAAKYwzEbZdpgSqdSvY8KTXrjAQADAgADbQADLQQ", "file_unique_id": "*****", "file_size": 23267, "width": 320, "height": 180}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkDAAIBsGPMLp2JSUJTTnhbrEhMsgyqbdvoAAKYwzEbZdpgSqdSvY8KTXrjAQADAgADeAADLQQ", "file_unique_id": "******", "file_size": 137005, "width": 800, "height": 450}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkDAAIBsGPMLp2JSUJTTnhbrEhMsgyqbdvoAAKYwzEbZdpgSqdSvY8KTXrjAQADAgADeQADLQQ", "file_unique_id": "*****", "file_size": 270412, "width": 1280, "height": 720}]}>]
```

**Помогите, как вытащить отсюда message_id!**

P.S. Некоторые значения я зацензурил, так что пусть звездочки никого не смущают

Comment: 1) Что значит не сработало? Это как? Вылез гномик и сказал что не будет это выполнять? Обычно под не сработало подразумевают ошибку или неожиданный результат.
2) Похоже что mg -  массив, соответственно вам нужно выбрать элемент массива.

Comment: Все оказалось проще, в отличии от сообщения, которые представляют собой словарь, медиагруппы представляют собой массив (словарь словарей). Соответственно, пришлось разбирать с помощью промежуточных переменных до состояния обычного словаря. `mg = await message.answer_media_group(media_group)
    mg_0 = mg[0]
    mg_id = mg_0['message_id']`    Костыльное немного решение, но работает

Comment: Возможно стоит просто сделать так: `mg_id = mg[0]['message_id']`?